# When and how to use lock()?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, .net-4.5

I'm currently working on a multithreaded project. Mainly for learning purposes.
My part in this project is to write a server application.
But I got to a point where this whole locking of variables is a bit confusing because I don't know exactly how it works and when/where I have to use it.

Lets say I have a `class ClientHandler` that contains a `List<Client> clientList`.
`ClientHandler` has a property `ClientList` that returns `clientList`:

```
private List<Client> clientList;
public List<Client> ClientList
{
    get { lock (lockObject) return clientList; }
    set { lock (lockObject) clientList = value; }
}
```

`NetworkHandler` runs a second `Thread` that works with this `List<>`.
In this network `Thread` the retrieved `List<>` is locked with another `object` while in use.
My question is how this locking works.
If I `lock` this `List<>` in the network `Thread` (with a different `object` than `ClientHandler`) is it thread-safe? So in general is it true that if you `lock` a variable with whatever `object`, is it locked for everyone else trying to access it?
I just want to be sure that the `List<>` cannot be altered while it is processed in another `Thread`.

Comment: You are locking just the getting and the setting. Not the manipulation of the list itself.

Comment: consider using a concurrent collection.

Comment: @meilke Is it even not locked if I lock the returned List<Client> by the thread requesting it?

Comment: Listen to @DanielA.White, but you need to lock the adding/removing clearing accesses of the list object.

Comment: I'm not sure about .NET but you don't typically 'lock a variable'.  You place a lock on a section of code you want to make thread safe, sometimes called the critical section. Your variable is thread safe if its manipulated within these locks which are sometimes named for primary variable that is manipulated within them, using the same lock for each time you want to modify the variable.

Comment: Threading and synchronization is not a simple topic. I'll suggest you to read this [article/book](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx) completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that you want the List itself to be passed around and manipulated on separate threads via Add/Remove/Clear/foreach methods, but **not** the objects themselves.

If this is the case then the List itself needs to implement an internal locking mechanism on each operation (Add, Remove, etc).  The List creates the `lockObject`, not you.

Obviously a `List<T>` can't do this, so you need to either derive from it or implement your own IList/ICollection class, or you can just use a collection from the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace which is designed for this purpose already, such as `ConcurrentDictionary`.

If you want to make the objects inside the collection accessible by multiple threads then you have to make those objects thread safe... which is a completely separate step.

For a brief explanation of how the lock keyword works:

When you lock an object by specifying `lock (someObject) { }`, everything inside the code block will only be executed when every other instance of a lock on that same object is not executing.

At the start of the lock code block it sets a thread-safe flag somewhere that says "I'm reserving this object", and at the end of the lock block it says "I am no longer reserving this object."  At the start of the lock block if it tries to lock an object but that object is already locked then it will wait indefinitely until it can successfully obtain a lock, blocking the calling thread in the process.

In your example you are using an inline code block:

`get { lock (lockObject) return clientList; }`

Which is equivalent to:

```
get
{
    lock (lockObject)
    {                       // Lock starts here
        return clientList;
    }                       // Lock ends here
}
```

So if you access that property then the object is unlocked as soon as its given to the caller of the property.  Then the caller can go ahead and call the Add() method on that List and internally it will access the inner collection with no locking mechanism, so it won't be thread safe.

Instead, the List needs to call lock everytime it accesses the internal fields, such as the `_innerList` field, like so:

```
public void Add(object item)
{
    lock (_innerList)
    {
        _innerList.Add(item);
    }
}
```